# Dynamically rotate text horizontally in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I would like to add a functionality to rotate text horizontally in jquery plugin. I found one plugin called `jqueryrain` but it is rotating 360 deg clock/anti-clock wise.

[image]

Comment: Try [CSS Transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

Comment: Its should rotate when moveover on the text